# Border lines animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I do the same thing with Javascript or jQuery?

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ppynxokq/

With css it also works, but when the last line is done I need the lines to start all over again. Also the last `<li>` element border-right line has to animate aswell.

Any ideas? 
Thanks?

Answer (score 1):

set the border-right for last li using the `last-child` selector.

```css
li {
      list-style-type:none;    
      }
      a {
        float:left;
        font-size: 26px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 50px 35px;
        border-left: 1px solid transparent;
        -webkit-animation: fadeinout 1s linear forwards;
        animation: fadeinout 1s linear forwards;
        }
         a:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }
        li:last-child a:after{
          content: '';
          height: 100%;
          width: 0px;
          border-right: 1px solid transparent;          
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
          -webkit-animation: fadeinout 1s linear forwards;
          animation: fadeinout 1s linear forwards;
          -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
          animation-delay: 3s;
          padding:50px 35px 50px 0;
        }

      @-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
        0%   { border-color: transparent}
        50%  { border-color: black}
        100% { border-color: transparent }
      }


    li:first-child > a {
        left: 9.5%;     
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
        animation-delay: 0.5s;
    }
    li:nth-child(2) > a {
        left: 19.5%;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
        animation-delay: 1s;
    }
    li:nth-child(3) > a {
        left: 29.6%;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
        animation-delay: 1.5s;
    }
    li:nth-child(4) > a {
        left: 39.6%;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
        animation-delay: 2s;
    }
    li:nth-child(5) > a {
        left: 49.7%;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
        animation-delay: 2.5s;
    }
    li:nth-child(6) > a {
        left: 59.8%;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
        animation-delay: 3s;
    }
    li:nth-child(7) > a {
        left: 69.9%;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
        animation-delay: 3.5s;
    }
    li:nth-child(8) > a {
        left: 80%;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
        animation-delay: 4s;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
       <li><a>one</a></li>
    
       <li><a>two</a></li>
    
       <li><a>three</a></li>
    
       <li><a>four</a></li>
    
       <li><a>five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: border-left and border-right line are not allowed to appear at the same time. @z0mBi3

Comment: I have edited the code to add the delay.. Use after pseudo element to get the right line and delay in transition.

Comment: Yes, it works! Is it possible to also restart the lines with css? @z0mBi3

Comment: What do you imply by restart the lines?

Comment: I mean, when the last border-line has disappeared the first one appears again etc. Like a loop or something i guess. Without clicking anywhere the lines finish and then start again.